# Except estimation and testing, is there something else to statistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation

Statistical methods can be used for hypothesis testing in various forms, such as null hypothesis testing.

They can also be used to estimate the value of some parameter plus an uncertainty of that value, be it using standard errors, confidence intervals, or credible intervals. Both of these goals can be achieved with some philosophical differences using frequentist or Bayesian methods.

My question is, is there something else besides testing or estimation, that statistical methods are used for?

Comment: How many tags are there on this website that have little to do with estimation and testing?

Comment: in hindsight,  "estimation" and "testing" sounds like a great tags compared ot tags I choosed originally

Comment: Descriptive statistics -- certainly including exploratory data analysis and many graphical or visualization methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: [prediction](/questions/tagged/prediction) or [forecasting](/questions/tagged/forecasting).

Most so-called "Machine Learning" is almost exclusively concerned with this, with estimation ("learning") only as a necessary tool for prediction. But of course you can also use "classical" statistical tools for prediction, like a linear model or ARIMA.

Answer (score 1):

more broadly, design and analysis:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_theory